# Keeping the nextcloud folder structure safe from user editing / deletions and giving the users freedom for the content

Tags: nextcloud

I am setting up a nextcloud instance where i need the following:

All users belonging to a specific group to be able to add/edit/remove files , BUT i need them to NOT be able alter the folder structure.

For example i have a folder structure like:

```
Folder 1 → Folder 1-2 → Subfolder 1-3
Folder 2 → Folder 2-1 → Subfolder 2-3
```

I need the users to be able upload, delete, download files in sub folders but not being able to delete the parent folder structure.

- They should be able to create/remove/update files and folders under the Subfolder 1-3 and Subfolder 2-3
- They shouldn't be able to do anything to the initial folder structure.

The files are in external storage (local).

I tried sharing Folder 1 and Folder 2 and adjusting the permissions but when i add it to the user, he is able to delete the parent folder from the Actions menu.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I doubt this is possible out of the box, so without you writing a special app for your very specific goal. Reason is that this is not the idea behind nextcloud. In nextcloud users are meant to have control over their own content. Maybe what you are looking for is more something like a simple web based file manager (there are some around). For those you can simply change file system based ownership of those folders to a server side user account that is different from the one used by the file manager logic.

Comment: Or maybe sharing those subfolders is already enough for what you have in mind?

Comment: @arkascha Exactly my thoughts. The only issue is that i need to have permalinks for the files in order to attach them to SAP as URL and i need this to be permanent for each file regardless if the file is renamed of moved to another folder. And nextcloud does this very well. I ended up adjusting file-level permissions to nextcloud external storage folders and even if the delete command is there, users cannot delete the parent folders.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Group Folders.
https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/groupfolders

Creating Group Folders is an Admin task. You can give specific User Group permissions within the folder but they would need to be an Admin to change them.

Creating the first level folder you just give it a name:
Folder

Creating the second level:
Folder/SubFolder

Comment: I have seen this,a and if you see the comments below the link you sent you will see everyone having issues with that. It seems unpolished to the degree that it is not for production use.

Comment: Fair enough, it works for my use case, I linked to the official app page. I cannot speak for others.